# What is a common way to handle http errors when using jcabi-http client?

Tags: java, http, client, jcabi

I just started using `jcabi`'s fluent http client and I feel like I am missing some general error handling routines (I believe each `jcabi-http` user faces it).

So, for a start there's always `IOException` when I use `fetch()` or `json().readObject()` and my first attempt looks like this:

```
try {
    return new JdkRequest("http://localhost")
            .uri()
                ...
                .back()
            .method(Request.GET)
            .fetch()
            .as(JacksonResponse.class)
                .json().readObject()
                ...;
} catch (IOException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
```

Next, when response's status in not 200 OK, then `json().readObject()` fails with the error that "this is not a json you gave me". So I add status check:

```
try {
    return new JdkRequest("http://localhost")
            ...
            .fetch()
            .as(RestResponse.class)
                .assertStatus(HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK)
            .as(JacksonResponse.class)
                ...;
} catch (IOException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
```

With this when status is not 200 OK I receive AssertionError, which I have to handle to give it some business meaning:

```
try {
    return new JdkRequest("http://localhost")
            ...
            .fetch()
            .as(RestResponse.class)
                .assertStatus(HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK)
            .as(JacksonResponse.class)
                ...;
} catch (IOException ex) {
    throw new RuntimeException(ex);
}
} catch (AssertionError error) {
    wrapBusiness(error);
}
```

Next when I want to get different behavior for 401, 403, 404 of 5xx statuses, then my code will transform into something like this:

```
try {
    val response = new JdkRequest("http://localhost")
            ...
            .fetch()
            .as(RestResponse.class);
    HttpStatusHandlers.of(response.status()).handle();
    return response
            .as(JacksonResponse.class)
            ...;
} catch (IOException ex) {
    throw new RuntimeException(ex);
}
```

This "code evolution" looks like a common pattern and I am reinventing the wheel.

**Maybe there's an already implemented (or described) solution (or a Wire.class)?**

Answer (score 0):

You are doing everything correctly. `IOException` will happen if there is some network problem, `AssertionError` is flying out `assert*()` methods. The rest is up to your business logic.

A few examples:

- https://github.com/yegor256/wring/blob/0.17.2/src/main/java/io/wring/agents/github/AgGithub.java#L89-L131
- https://github.com/yegor256/takes/blob/1.7/src/main/java/org/takes/facets/auth/social/PsGithub.java#L167-L190
- https://github.com/jcabi/jcabi-github/blob/0.33/src/main/java/com/jcabi/github/RtForks.java#L106-L119

Comment: I mean the code looks like boilerplate that could be already implemented in projects using jcabi-http. Could you show how it's done in your projects, please?